# How to align numbers in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm using [Playfair Display](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Playfair+Display?query=play) (Google Font) in one of my pages.

This is how number show in the page. They're all unaligned. Below is the picture.

[image: Unaligned fonts]

Below is the picture of Aligned Fonts of the same Google Font. (I have taken the pic from Figma, there was a option for changing font style in Figma) I have to make my fonts look like this, how do I do that?

[image: Aligned Fonts]

Comment: Those numbers are all aligned on the baseline. Their ascenders and descenders are designed differently from what you expect. If you don’t like the design, use a different font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by adding CSS instructing the browser to use the lining-figures.
Read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-variant-numeric/)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
  font-feature-settings: "lnum";
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

123456789
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this!

```css
h1, p {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-feature-settings: "lnum";
}

.number {
    background: #55bd55;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<h1>Sample Header</h1>
<p class="number">123456789</p>

</body>
</html>
```